# How to vertically align the items in the div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

```css
.features {
  background-color: #0375b4;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.features img {
  width: 100px;
}

.features-content {
  text-align: center;
}

.features-content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="features">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Adventure</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Fun &amp; Safety</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Impeccable Service</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The items in the div are not vertically aligned . How do I properly align the items in the middle of the div? The picture in the last div is smaller than the pictures in other div so it has gone up. how to put all the pictures in the middle?

Comment: why are you using row class if you want to align them vertical ?

Comment: Please provide working snippet code.

Comment: the screen shot you attached is different comparing with your provided snippet

Comment: the image height could be the problem, add the same images to your snippet so people could figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by specifying the desired image height (that of the other two images) to the `img` dom element.

In this case, we apply the following CSS rules to `.features-content img`

```
.features-content img {
  object-fit: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

---

#### Complete example

```css
.features {
  background-color: #0375b4;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.features img {
  width: auto;
}

.features-content {
  text-align: center;
}

.features-content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.features-content img {
  object-fit: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="features">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Adventure</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Fun &amp; Safety</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x100" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Impeccable Service</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Click the full screen button on the upper-right portion of the code snippet in order to see a wider view with items side-by-side; as shown in your example screenshot.*

Answer (score 0):

you can use following css property -

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

[You can check in detail on here](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/oJeAK)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 4 just add `d-flex align-items-center` to `row` class to align vertically center.

In your case,

the third column `h1` text length is grater when compare to other two so there is some issue in the design.

```css
features{
  background-color: #0375b4;
  padding:40px 100px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  }

 .features img{
    width: auto;
  }

 .features-content{
    text-align: center;
  }

.features-content h1{
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #000;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="features">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="features-content">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/70x70/000/fff" alt="Compass Logo">
            <h1>Adventure</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="features-content">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/70x70/000/fff" alt="Compass Logo">
            <h1>Fun &amp; Safety</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="features-content">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/70x70/000/fff" alt="Compass Logo">
            <h1>Impeccable Service</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add vertical-align for images, and margin:0 auto; for div container.

```css
.features{
  background-color: #0375b4;
  padding:40px 100px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  }

 img{
    width: auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
  }

 .features-content{
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
     display:inline-block;
      margin:0 auto;
  }

.features-content h1{
 font-size:12px;
 margin:0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="features-content">
            <img src="images/compass.png" alt="Compass Logo">
            <h1>Adventure</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="features-content">
            <img src="images/tube.png" alt="Compass Logo">
            <h1>Fun &amp; Safety</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="features-content">
            <img src="images/diamond.png" alt="Compass Logo">
            <h1>Impeccable Service</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```