# How to properly align the items in the div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Achieved
[image]

Want
[image]

as seen in the first picture the items are not properly aligned how can it be aligned like on the second picture? Here's the code I tried. Vertical-align attribute also doesn't seem to work, or may be i used it wrong.

```css
    .features{
      background-color: #0375b4;
      padding:40px 100px;
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .features img{
      width: auto;
    }


    .features-content{
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      margin:0 auto;
    }

     .features-content h1{
      font-size: 24px;
     color: #ffffff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
     margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="features">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
              <div class="features-content">
                <img src="images/compass.png" alt="Compass Logo">
                <h1>Adventure</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
              <div class="features-content">
                <img src="images/tube.png" alt="Compass Logo">
                <h1>Fun &amp; Safety</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
              <div class="features-content">
                <img src="images/diamond.png" alt="Compass Logo">
                <h1>Impeccable Service</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically align the items in the div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427256/how-to-vertically-align-the-items-in-the-div)

Comment: try fooling around with `vertical-align:`, `display:`, and `padding:`

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError  yes, i felt like i didnt present my question correctly their so i had to repost .

Comment: Couldn't you update your existing question?

Comment: the problem is that your uploaded images are not the same height. Make them the same either with CSS either before uploading them

Comment: You should learn about flexboxes: once you'll have read this (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) you won't need bootstrap anymore for positioning/grid/alignment.

Comment: You can't use vertical align on bootstrap element because is floated. You can change its behavior using display flex or not using bootstrap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vertical-align with Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your uploaded images are not the same height.

**A.** Make them the same either with CSS either before uploading them

See below example with changing height with css ( i changed the class `col-xs-12` to `col-xs-4` for example purposes only, so they will be 3 in row in the snippet )

```css
.features {
  background-color: #0375b4;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.features img {
  width: auto;
}

.features-content {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.features-content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.features-content img{
  height:150px;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="features">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Adventure</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x250" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Fun &amp; Safety</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x200" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Impeccable Service</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**B.** Or you can make the cols same height an position the text absolutely at the bottom if you don't want to change the height of the images ( if you want your images to have different heights )

```css
.features {
  background-color: #0375b4;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.features img {
  width: auto;
  max-width:100%;
}

.features-content {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.features-content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.features .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.features .row > div {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  /*for visual example*/
}

.features .row > div h1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="features">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Adventure</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x250" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Fun &amp; Safety</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x200" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Impeccable Service</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**C.** The least 'clean' solution would be to add specific padding-bottom or margin-bottom to the images until the `h1` are aligned. ( same with margin-top or padding-top to the `h1` )

```css
.features {
  background-color: #0375b4;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.features img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%
}

.features-content {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.features-content h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.features .col-md-4:first-child img {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.features .col-md-4:last-child img {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="features">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Adventure</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x250" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Fun &amp; Safety</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="features-content">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x200" alt="Compass Logo">
          <h1>Impeccable Service</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```